# Question involving square equality between fractions and square roots

Tags: problem-solving

Find the values of the constants $p$ and $q$ such that $$\frac{\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{p}+2p} = \frac{2\sqrt{p}-q}{3p+q} \tag{$p,q\ge0$}$$
How would you solve this? I've tried everything...

Comment: @Fabien Thats what the anwser is, but is there no way to actually get those values though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a condition missing since if there's only one equation for 2 unknowns, the number of solution is infinite.
I've got 
$$
(p,q)=(p,\frac{p\sqrt{p}+2p}{2p+2\sqrt{p}})
$$
For example, $(2,1)$ works

**EDIT**
We've got
$$
\sqrt{p}(3p+q)=(\sqrt{p}+2p)(2\sqrt{p}-q)
$$
which is legit since the divisers are positives
$$
3p\sqrt{p}+q\sqrt{p}=2p-q\sqrt{p}++4p\sqrt{p}-2pq
$$
$$
2q\sqrt{p}+2pq=2p+p\sqrt{p}
$$
$$
q=\frac{p\sqrt{p}+2p}{2p+2\sqrt{p}}
$$
I assumed that the question was for p,q positives integers, otherwise the number of solution is too big.
You can easily see that for p=2, q=1

Comment: Thats what the anwser is, but is there no way to actually get those values though?

Comment: I'll edit to show the all thing

Comment: With pleasure ;)

Answer (score 3):

Let $a = \sqrt{p}$, and $b = q $, then: $\dfrac{a}{a + 2a^2} = \dfrac{2a - b}{3a^2 + b}$.

So: $3a^3 + ab = 2a^2 - ab + 4a^3 - 2a^2b$ or:

$a^3 + (2 - 2b)a^2 - 2ab = 0$. Thus:

$a(a^2 + (2 - 2b)a - 2b) = 0$, since $a \neq 0$, we have: $a^2 + (2 - 2b)a - 2b = 0$, and use quadratic formula:

$\triangle' = (1 - b)^2 + 2b = 1 + b^2$. So:

$a = -1 + b + \sqrt{1 + b^2}$  ( the other root is negative so we can't take it ). So:

$p = a^2 = \left(-1 + q + \sqrt{1 + q^2}\right)^2$.

**Specifically**, choose $q = 1$, then $p = 2$.

Comment: The anwser is p=2 and q=1 , but is there no way to actually get those values though?